# UploadValuesAsync and getting some data back

Tags: php, vb.net, visual-studio, webclient

I'm trying to improve one of my projects (LJTD), written in Visual Basic.net. First of all I want to show what the actual code is:

```
 Dim wc2 As New Net.WebClient
 Dim nvc = Module_NVC.NVC_Create("SomeString123456789")
 Dim downloadString = wc2.UploadValues(New Uri(linkToPHPFile), nvc)
```

That works pretty good. It uploads some data to the server and is getting back a String. The problem is that it's not async and causes a user having a bad ping that can lead to huge spikes in the application itself. So it's getting unusable. That's why I tried to enable async functionaliy:

```
Dim wc2 As New Net.WebClient
AddHandler wc2.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf Download_Completed
Dim nvc = Module_NVC.NVC_Create("SomeString123456789")
Dim downloadString = wc2.UploadValuesAsync(New Uri(linkToPHPFile), nvc)
```

The problem is located in the last line. The reason is that *UploadValuesAsync* does not allow to get back data like the *UploadValues* ([Library](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=M%3aSystem.Net.WebClient.UploadValues%28System.Uri,System.String,System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection%29))

### Backgroundinformation

If you would like to know how my php-file looks like, here you go:

```
<?php
include 'inc/db-connect.php';
if (isset($_POST['teamID'])) {
  $teamID = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['teamID']);
} 
$sql="SELECT scaleX,scaleY FROM wardmap WHERE teamID = '$teamID';";
$result = $db->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
    echo "\r\n$row->scaleX $row->scaleY";
$db->close();
?>
```

### So my question is

How can I upload a `NameValueCollection Async` and download the data PHP has written with `echo`.

If you know another way without `UploadValuesAsync` you're also welcome. Just give me some tips. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got help in vb-paradise.

Now the solution:

```
Dim wc2 As New Net.WebClient AddHandler wc2.UploadValuesCompleted, AddressOf Download_Completed 
Dim nvc = NVCGetWard_Create("SomeString123456789") 
wc2.UploadValuesAsync(New Uri(linkToPHPFile), nvc)
```

And then you need the Callback:

```
Private Sub Download_Completed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UploadValuesCompletedEventArgs) 
Dim Result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Result) 
End Sub
```

Pretty simple